# How do I create a passthrough function that returns the same type of the parameter passed in. e.g. a logging function

Tags: typescript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to create a quick logging function that I could pass in an argument and know that the return type will be the same and thus preserve type checking.

> aside: In my case the system being used is NetSuite. I develop in Typescript whenever possible (especially new scripts) however, this is not specifically a NetSuite problem.

> NetSuite has a global logging method available at all times and has deployment options to throttle it's impact /output.  if only it returned what you passed it natively :(.

### Q: How do i create a function that passes the same types that are provided to a function?

I am adding some in-line logging in a system and my "logger" was returning `any` which had a side effect of eliminating type checking.

I modified that to return `unknown` and while it does flag typechecking it requires type conversion to be accurate -- that seems unnecessary

The function I have is:

```
import * as Nlog from "N/log";  // this is the module definition

declare const log : typeof Nlog;  // this is the global method of it that i want to leverage

export const L = (details: unknown, options : { title? : string; method?: keyof typeof log | 'skip' } = {}) : typeof details => {
 const { title, method } = {
    title : 'auto-logging',
    method : 'debug',
    ...options
  };

  if (method === 'skip' || typeof Nlog[method] !== 'function') return details;

  try {
    log[method]({ title, details });
  } catch (e) {
    log.error({
      title : 'error in auto-logging',
      details : e
    });
  }

  return details;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

With a simple trick you can define a generic that will be used at runtime.

The important part

```
export const L = <T>(passthru: T, options : { title? : string; method?: keyof typeof Nlog | 'skip' } = {}) : T => {
```

example of all three (good, bag, ugly) at
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&jsx=0&module=2&pretty=true&isolatedModules=true&suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wHIBsIHM4BmUEIcARBgPQ65kDccAUIwCYCmAxlslG3BxAB2qeDTgAuODACeYNhAKYadZgOHwAMgQCugjjGBD0AXjgBvRnDgAjZC0kAKdjGTAsqSckHSANHAhgBkYS5lLAMFhsAPwhIlDAgrgMIGwwABYQLFGSANZs0gpSsvKKYgA+cADkqDnAYJVwAL5wpmaNAJQhMnKFzq7uLQB85pZW-EbwZmERbH4p6ZlNLSNjYwYzIZXI2jAQALQ0uAm4lT6jq-MZLJvs1tonZ6tWAHSvAUHC500qo8CKDpdFsZgVUanUGmUKt0Sko8ABtQEsAC6cAAhCDKjo9B9Kp1eDBtFBBHA+m5UD8rDAoNIVmMaAjUlckQ4putIn5SQMOiorM0OMgYBw0nAHGxOhZVjRnmwoMQoCyvpTwpFNjK5XAEigdvtDsdToqSal+uhJGwvtzRo1mFZ8YTiZzyYxGo84PcsDTHA7JLocoIIAB3QR+d6GYQhVnK6KxKnHZKMzLZOB5AqKaGFcqg2r1JatDpdYq9I1koa0tQiUJs2ZwRE52mrSubba7A54I6JfVPavx66SSq3e4dp6vZ4hozmiljP4imvA0zVLMQqEFxTYeGIlHoudY-Sh3FwW1Ew0uMkTynUut0tfd5kRmYcotc9o8sZ8gVCkVii9WKVq6AKztKhsva-lAGrEk2OqtnqLqdg6IRmp2FqrFaXwHvaD6OryLq4BAiySAAPAAKnAbAAB4wGwggsOgPp+oGgxOBhkiEcGgShiaFaRomcSxl2CxZLk+SFGmpR4HAFTzuCtZtJ04jEcYwwSuM6icXefFXNJBoNr2EEtrgbYPAaNa9v2hmdsOo6fMhp4av8M4YmC2aQkUPQrvS65ohi244niqR2kexo2VSNJKZKV78Te0zsgFxZIS+-BvsKorigaP6yn+oVPNpVQgWBWrNrq7YwU8cGmgacW8taYxoTF7jPlaKGMGWmjLFoug7kYzw4ZkDCUJQcAaLY1x9QNbrSAwTUTHA3U9nAgjaCA1gylYpgaA4mK4biDBwCNyAuZwaScLUiQkeloHpAKGroIdWBgDoWAisA0rPHAPEncA6B+vAaCoMAuCCMg1gqrsc0LUtUDtJNKlDSE82Lctq3eexzxDetBCbU+VgjX6p3qsOLBeLgMoQNoqBQ+WY2w2DCMDUjnVjWjGMoJ91OgdtI0QDkNg7HNEDDswa1mDNPhDX4Y3ckAA)

It's common to see Netsuite code littered with `log.debug` statements. Now you can more easily do something like this which will login in line but also respect existing types.

```
record.setValue(L({fieldId : 'email', value : 'gg@suitegeezus.obvious'}));
```